# Can't connect to self hosted Tezos node (Docker setup)

Tags: node, docker, connections

I'm trying to set up a new local node for Jakartanet using the docker setup, as I've done in the past for previous testnets.
Unfortunately, no matter how I try to setup the node, it seems to fail to connect to it with the following error

```
./jakartanet.sh head
Warning:
  Failed to acquire the protocol version from the node
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: http://node:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ECONNREFUSED, "connect", "")"

Error:
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: http://node:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/header
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ECONNREFUSED, "connect", "")"
```

I've tried to run the node using just `./jakartanet.sh node start`, or using `./jakartanet.sh node start --rpc-port 8732 --rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:8732 --allow-all-rpc 0.0.0.0:8732`, and most combinations of only some of the parameters.
When I'm trying to curl directly it also refused to connect

```
curl http://localhost:8732/version
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm currently not using a snapshot, but earlier I tried to do the same with a snapshot and had similar issues.
Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known bug. You can track it here: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/3280

**edit**: original issue https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/2972